Python multiprocessing not using 100% CPU for perfectly parallel, CPU-limited problem
I am trying to parallelize the execution of a python code that solves a numerical problem. It's a relatively complicated code making heavy use of numpy. I want to solve the numerical problem for a large set of parameters. This should be easy to parallelize: just let different processes solve the problem for different regions of the parameter space.
Here is some (pseudo-)code illustrating how I attempted the parallelization over a 2D parameter space:
import numpy as np
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool
import MyNumericalProblemSolver

chunksize = 100
n_values_per_param = 50
n_processes = 8
p1_values = np.logspace(1,2,n_values_per_param)
p2_values = np.logspace(3,5,n_values_per_param)
param_iterator = itertools.product(p1_values,p2_values)
solver = MyNumericalProblemSolver()
def wrapper(params):
    p1,p2 = params
    solver.set_parameters(p1=p1,p2=p2)
    solver.solve()

p = Pool(n_processes)
p.map(wrapper,param_iterator,chunksize=chunksize)

Execution of the above code typically takes several minutes. My laptop has 8 CPUs (output of multiprocessing.cpu_count()), so I expect a performance improvement of roughly a factor 8. However, what I see is an improvement of only a factor 1.5.
The interesting thing is the CPU usage:

If I don't use multiprocessing, then 1 process is using 100% CPU
n_processes = 1: 1 process is using 100% CPU
n_processes = 2: 2 processes, each using 100% CPU
n_processes = 4: 4 processes, each using 50% CPU
n_processes = 8: 8 processes, each using 25% CPU

So it looks like the maximum total usage is 200%. I don't understand why this is happening. I confirmed that when I start the program without multiprocessing in 8 different terminals, I get 8 processes each using 100%. Things I tried so far:

change the chunksize; doesn't help, small or large chunk sizes give the same performance
there are several similar questions mentioning that numpy (and other libraries) can mess with the core affinity (e.g. Why does multiprocessing use only a single core after I import numpy?, multiprocessing not achieving full CPU usage on dual-processor windows machine, Multiprocessing.Pool makes Numpy matrix multiplication slower). So I tried os.system(f"taskset -p 0xff {os.getpid()}") to reset the CPU affinity after importing numpy, but it doesn't change anything. If I do os.sched_getaffinity(0) before and after importing numpy, I get the same output: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}.

As a test to see if this is a numpy issue, I wrote this small script:
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

matrix_dim = 100
n_processes = 8

def test_function(x):
    for i in range(5000):
        matrix = np.random.rand(matrix_dim,matrix_dim)
        np.linalg.solve(matrix,np.ones(matrix_dim))

n_iter = 100
chunksize = 10
p = Pool(n_processes)
p.map(test_function,range(n_iter),chunksize=chunksize)

This gives 8 processes that all use 100% CPU, so it does not seem to be a numpy problem. EDIT: not always, I sometimes see the same behaviour as described above, where 8 processes use 25% CPU each. And, testing different values of n_processes between 1 and 8, no performance difference is seen.
At this point I am running out of ideas of how to tackle this issue. I am running all this in a conda virtual env using python 3.11 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Outputs requested in the comments:
from cat /proc/cpuinfo: model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz

Output of hwloc-ps -t when the program is running:
142024  Core:0      python
142025  Core:0      python
142026  Core:0      python
142027  Core:0      python
142028  Core:0      python
142029  Core:0      python
142030  Core:0      python
142031  Core:0      python


Output of hwloc-ls: screenshot of hwloc-ls output

Welcome to stack overflow. What is your exact CPU reference (you can get it using cat /proc/cpuinfo)? Note that AFAIK operation not in the main are executed by all processes so the work is replicated. Also note that sending data to workers can be sometimes quite slow and serialized (since the master process can be slower than workers and workers can starve matching with your results).

Thank you @JérômeRichard ! Sorry I don't know what "CPU reference" means, which parts of cat /proc/cpuinfo would you like to see?
I checked what happens if I put the Pool into if __name__=='__main__', outcome is the same.
I think I see what you mean by the starved workers. Is there a way I can check if that's the case here?
I also just updated the question with another test I did: a small script using a numpy function uses all 8 CPUs at 100%, suggesting it's not a numpy issue.

Regarding /proc/cpuinfo, it should be the "model name". For example, "Intel core i5-9600KF CPU @ 4.5 GHz". For the workers, I do not know : I used to look whether worker process are actually using the CPU and whether the master one does, like you do. Regarding the processes placement, you can use hwloc-ps so to see how they are bound to cores. You can also use hwloc-ls to see your CPU topology (adding both in your question can help if this is the problem). Note BLAS library can AFAIK bind threads to cores (sometimes inefficiently).

Regarding your test, It is not clear was you do. We have neither the code of the test nor the complete code of your program so it is hard to know what is happening or even to reproduce the problem. For example, if the problem is in MyNumericalProblemSolver, then we cannot help you.

Thanks @JérômeRichard. I added the code of the additional test, and the requested outputs to the question.
Yes I understand that it's hard to help without the full code, and without being able to reproduce the problem. The full code is too long to be posted here. I just thought the pattern of CPU usage when increasing the number of requested cores n_CPUs is striking, and might give experienced people an idea of what is going on. I will try to investigate your idea that the master process might be slower than the workers.

I realised that my wording was confusing. When saying "8 CPUs using 100%", what I meant was 8 processes each using 100% CPU. I updated the question.

Your i7-7700HQ CPU has 4 cores, not 8. 8 is the number of threads your CPU can run (2 per core). This method (called SMT) helps programs to use more efficiently the cores but it tends not to be so great in practice (especially when the target thread execute optimized code) : one can expect a -5%/+20% in practice and generally just 5% in average. As a result, you should expect a 4x speed up, not 8. It might be eventually better due to SMT but you should not expect SMT to help a lot without good reasons.

Note that if the master process spend time in sending data to workers, then it will reserve a core so there is only 3 left for workers during this given time. Regarding the hwloc results, it seems good but you should add the flag to print threads since each process might spawn thread. BLAS can do that and often does. If such a thing happen, then you should tell to your BLAS implementation not to create threads. Note that it also means that the serial implementation was actually already parallel too (so using more processes does not help much). See e.g. the env variable OMP_NUM_THREADS.

Last but not least, your CPU is a low-power one so when many cores are running, it reduce the frequency of the cores so to stay in the power budget. When one core runs, it increase the frequency (this is called "turbo boost") to 3.80 GHz one your CPU compared to the base one which is 2.8 GHz. This means You should not see a 4x speed up. In practice the speed up is dependent of the actual operation performed on cores. For intensive ones, you should get a 2.8*4/3.8 ~= 3x speed up.

Thanks again @JérômeRichard. Your comments prompted me to check how the performance of the small test script changes if I change the number of processes; of course should have done this from the start :-(. The first or second time there is a significant performance improvement when using more processes, but subsequent executions yield no performance difference regardless of the number of processes. That could be because of the CPU temperature, or the power budged?
Also, I added -t to the hwloc-ps, but the output is the same as before.

I think my fundamental mis-conception was to assume that the total CPU percentage I see with top is inversely proportional to the execution time. I now understand that this is not true because of various factors.
@JérômeRichard Are you going do write an answer? Otherwise I will accept the answer by user3666197. Thanks again for your help.


Q : "(...) when I start the program without multiprocessing in 8 different terminals, I get (...)?"

Changing the realm of an experiment does not solve the original. Having this said, re-read the actual version of multiprocessing documentation to realise what was the default ( not explicitly set in the call-signature ) value for the multiprocessing methods ( some O/S have had "thread"-(only)-based backends as default, which translates into remaining in a pure-SERIAL, GIL-dictated, zero-CONCURRENT ( as Guido von Rossum postulated for concurrency-avoidance in accessing objects inside Python interpreter ), no matter how many CPU-cores you try to map the processing over ).

Some other O/S have other default backends ( some using full-copies of the Python process to avoid a "shared-herd-of-threads-suffering" inside a common GIL-lock cage ) and these defaults also change from version to version, so unless you specify the actual backend explicitly, in the imperative call-signature specification ( as documented ), no one knows all details, that decide the one root cause of the observed behaviours.

Q : "My laptop has 8 CPU-s (...), so I expect a performance improvement of roughly a factor 8. "

Wrong.Some 60 years ago Dr. Gene Amdahl explained the reason why more, even infinitely many resources do not boost any improved processing orchestration beyond a limit of so called "diminished returns" ( so just adding more resources, here thought as CPU-cores, does not improve overall processing performance anymore ).
Tip:run & post actual output about your actual HW NUMA architecture - as from hwloc 's lstopo
Nextcomes the CPU starvation (explained, iirc, some 25 years back). Given your actual hardware might be a 2-channel DRAM device, why would anyone expect boosting performance, once after more CPU-resources were added, the ecosystem now turns out to be even more MEM-I/O-bottlenecked, than before such CPU-code addition?
Lastbut not least, again to the detriment of your expectations, comes thermal-throttling (unless you happen to have your hardware enjoy active-thermal-adapters, that keep CPU-cores, no matter how much heating under full-steam computing, cooled under about the 35 degC ). When a core temperature gets above some threshold, the hardware itself reduces clock-cycles, to avoid further heat on such a core, so as to protect it from overheating ( at a cost of your computations now running at remarkably lower CPU-core frequency )
Finally,again to the detriment of your expectations, actual hardware need not support "ideal" scaling, even if all previous points got solved, cooled and actual NUMA architecture ( see lstopo above ) reveals another performance boosting bottleneck - the actual Cache-Hierarchy, if L1, L2 or L3 resources are actually cooperatively co-used (read concurrently shared and the more damaging LRU-hit-rates and the more re-introducing a need to re-fetch data once pre-cached, but now LRU-evicted from multiple CPU-cores co-shared cache level, raising a need to re-fetch this data again from a "farther", slower cache, or even from the main DDR-memory).
The economy of costs( in TimeDOMAIN ) matters. A lot. Details matter. Remarkably.
Bonus :How did it happen to have a 3-CPU computer, as depicted above?

The total power-cap ( here embedded in the CPU design ) on powering the cores, as noted by @jérôme-richard above, was actually first used some 15 years ago, where major US HPC DataCentre needed to remain both High Performance Computing centre and do not overcome the DOE contracted power-supply limits. Their experimentations on cooperative-adaptations of CPU-core powering orchestrations yielded interesting insights, what might help to actually boost performance by lowering the power fed to CPU-cores, circumventing the silicon-based power-throttling and gaining extra perfromance this way ...
